# How to check value getting none in modelserializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am having one issue

```
class PetSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Pet
        fields = '__all__'
```

How to check this serializer getting an object or none ...

If there is value in backend it returns correct format .

But if there is no value it return none only .

So I need to change that response to a string 'none'

Comment: observation: `get_color` `get_category` and `get_photo` aren't needed. No need to declare them as `SerializerMethodField()` as well

Comment: Please provide the call you do to get `None` otherwise it's just guessing

Comment: Check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run validations on the serializer object itself, you can override the `validate` method of the serializer class:

```py
class PetSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Pet
        fields = '__all__' 

    def validate(self, fields):
        # you can also use `fields['name']` but that
        # would raise a KeyError if 'name' is not defined
        if not fields.get('name'):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                detail="pet needs a name :(",
                code="E_NO_PET_NAME"
            )

        if fields.get('species').lower() == "dinosaur":
           raise serializers.ValidationError(
                detail="can't have a dinosaur as pet",
                code="E_TOO_RECKLESS"
            )


        return fields
        # or run `super().validate(fields)`
```

Or if you only need to validate one field (e.g. pet's name), you can do just that:

```py
    ...
    def validate_name(self, name):
        if not name:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                detail="pet needs a name :(",
                code="E_NO_PET_NAME"
            )
```

References:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#validationerror

Comment: `validate()` will fail if data is `None`

Comment: @tuergeist I believe `super().validate(fields)` checks for any required fields (and any other restrictions set for the model).

Answer (score 0):

To check your input data in the serializer, just implement `validate` to your needs

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class PetSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Pet


    def validate(self, data):
        if data is None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("data is expected as dict()")
        if not data.get('name'):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("name is needed")

        return data
```

Look for Object Level Validation in the [DRF Docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation)